# Powershell error in Executing NUnit test

Tags: nunit, powershell-2.0, nunit-console

This might sound silly but I have been trying to execute a NUnit test using powershell script, had several attempts but no hope. is there different format or do I need to add a plugin?

Any help would be appriciated...

```
Command = "c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe" /config=Release "C:\projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit" 2>&1
```

> Output as below:
>
> PS C:\tests> "c:\Program Files\NUnit2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe" /config=Release
>
> "C:\projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit" 2>&1
>
> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator.
>
> At line:1 char:55 + "c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe" / <<<<
>
> config=Release "C:\projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit" 2>&1

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the mess in the top dialog, proper code version below

```
& 'c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.\bin\nunitconsole.exe' /config=Release C:\Projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't put the part

```
/config=Release
```

inside your quoted command text.

Your command should probably look like

```
"c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe /config=Release C:\projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit" 2>&1
```

... i didn't check nunit-console.exe command line options, but i suppose you already tested if the nunit command works.

Comment: Powershell point of view : you must put a '&' in the start of your line so it is not considered as a string but like a command to execute. | NUnit point of view : options like /config=Release must be come last

Comment: @Cédric Thanks for support on the nunit side ... considering the question i should rather have pointed out that assigning the command string to a variable needs $Command = "..."

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did help me out... using "" did not work but replacing them with '' does the trick :-)
Working command

& 'c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.\bin\nunitconsole.exe' /config=Release C:\Projects\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.nunit 2>&1

Much appreciated.